# Execute method on expression end in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, expression

I'm designing a custom task management system. For this I'm overloading the + and - operators so they gain an alternative meaning:

```
const auto& scope = fsm::enter +STATE_TO_SET -LOCK_TO_ACQUIRE;
```

You can imagine that STATE_TO_SET and LOCK_TO_ACQUIRE are both enum values which are "added" to the objects member variables one after another. Now, there should be a method in the `fsm::enter`-object that triggers once all + and - operations are done (e.g. to set the state and acquire the lock). Is this doable somehow in C++11?

Comment: I think you're trying to do something called RAII. The thing you want to execute at the end should be done in the destructor of some helper object. std::lock_guard works this way and unlocks a mutex.

Comment: @tomdol: Yes and no, the problem appears to be is that I want to free the locks at the end of scope BUT at the same time execute the full expression `fsm::enter +STATE_TO_SET -LOCK_TO_ACQUIRE` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Almost - this is a well-known solution. The `operator+` returns a wrapper object. Since this is a temporary, it's destroyed at the end of the full expression. And for that reason, its destructor can run the code you want.

The "almost" is because you use `auto&`. That will deduce the *temporary* type, and then refuse to bind a non-const reference. Is the `auto&` a hard requirement?

Comment: I'm using the destructor to return mutex and state at the end of automatic scope (like lock_guard). I thought of running a method on copy construct but i figured since C++17 copy elision this is not such a portable method. But you're right it should be const (edited question)

Comment: @glades: The problem is that in that case, `operator+` can't return a temporary, but has to return a non-const reference to `fsm::enter`. And references do not have destructors, so **nothing** runs at the end of the full expression. Binding references, which is the last operation, is just a built-in operation and cannot be overloaded or replaced.

Comment: @glades: And binding to a `const&` works differently: It performs life-time extension. of the bound temporary. The destructor will run when `scope` goes out of scope (eh.)

Comment: Fair enough, so what you're basically saying is that I can only trigger a method by using some kind of sentinel to the +/- sequence?

Comment: @glades: Specifically I say that the only code which runs at the end of an expression is the destruction of temporaries. In your example, the only two temporaries would be return values from the operators. The problem with a sentinel is that you cannot assume order of evaluation.

Comment: True, except when I overload something like the comma operator maybe.. but really all I want is to produce practical and easily understandable code for giving and taking mutexes or states. I thought the +/- solution was very neat because it allows to easily specify if the mutex should be taken or given.